# Equality in General Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We just started general vector spaces in my freshman Linear Algebra class. I have 2 questions about the equality of vectors :

1. Do we get to define what it means for 2 vectors to be equal? A somewhat similar question was asked here:

   [Meaning of equality in the vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310249/meaning-of-equality-in-the-vector-spaces)

but I didn't get a for sure answer to this.

2. Why do we assume that equality between vectors has the properties of equality like substitution and transitivity?

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality is a concept that is not only applicable to vectors. In general, if $\Phi(x)$ is any statement with free variable $x$, then $a=b$ shall imply  that $\Phi(a)\leftrightarrow \Phi(b)$. Conversely, if $\Phi(a)\leftrightarrow\Phi(b)$ holds for *all* possible $\Phi$, then we say $a=b$. These remarks can be seen as definition of equality (or more precisely, of all inferences allowed for statements involving the otherwise meaningless symbol "$=$").

Comment: Pardon my naivety but what exactly does the double headed arrow mean here ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "equality in vector spaces".

Linear algebra uses the same definition of "equality" as most other parts of mathematics, i.e., intuitively, two objects are equal if they are the same object.

In most branches of mathematics, all objects are actually sets, in which case the strict definition of equality is that two sets are equal if they contain the same elements.